# Validate user input in decimal form

Tags: python, validation, range, decimal

I need to validate user input as a decimal. My program needs to make sure that a student entering credit hours enters them within a range of 1-4.5, with 0 being "quit", and can't get my attempts to work. I've tried validating the input against a list and a range, and I get interesting errors when I do both.

list[1, 1.0, 1.5, 2, 2.0, 2.5, 3, 3.0, 3.5, 4, 4.0, 4.5]

```
credits = input('Enter the credits for the course. Enter 0 to quit.')

if credits in list:
     total = total + credits
     MAX = MAX + 1
else:
     print('You have entered an invalid number. The number of credits')
     print('must be between 1 and 4.5.')
     number = float(input(f'Enter the credits for Course {MAX} and Term, or enter 0 to exit:'))
     total = total + credits
     MAX = MAX + 1
```

I've also tried

```
credits = (1, 4.5)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string.  You seem to have realized that the second time you used it, but not the first.

Comment: When you wrote `list[1, 1.0, ...]`, did you mean `list = [1, 1.0, ...]`?

Comment: Should it be allowed to enter `1.7`, for example?

Comment: 1. You should not use `list`as a variable name its a buildin datatype 2. you might use `valid_values={"1", "1.0", "1.5", "2", "2.0", "2.5", "3", "3.0", "3.5", "4", "4.0", "4.5"} ` and check against the input (use a set not a list).  3. cast the given value to `float()` to add it to `credits`

Comment: What errors do you get for both attempts? Please [edit] your question to include these.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
total = 0
MAX = 0

credits = float(input('Enter the credits for the course. Enter 0 to quit.'))

if 1 <= credits <= 4.5 and credits % 0.5 == 0:
     total = total + credits
     MAX = MAX + 1
else:
     print('You have entered an invalid number. The number of credits')
     print('must be between 1 and 4.5.')
     number = float(input(f'Enter the credits for Course {MAX} and Term, or enter 0 to exit:'))
     total = total + credits
     MAX = MAX + 1
```

With this obviously edit the `total` and `MAX` value to be what you desire.

This will check to see if the inputted value is between the value of 1 and 4.5, if this isn't true it will move to the else statement.

Edit: As pointed out by @MarkRansom the question is intended to only accept inputs that are between 1 and 4.5 and only if they are a multiple of 0.5

Comment: It seems clear from the question that the intent is not to allow *any* values within the range, just the specific ones given.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see your point and have made a change in the code to accommodate for this.